# Randomize the order of a data array which as string as a column

Tags: python, numpy

I have the IRIS Dataset loaded fro text file -

```
data = np.genfromtxt('../Data/bezdekIris.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=[0,1,2,3,4],dtype=None)
```

this has the data in the format

```
ndarray [(5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa') 
 (4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa')
 (4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa') 
 (4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa')
 (5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa')]
```

How do I randomize the order

Comment: You can use `np.random.shuffle(data)`, be carful this function doesn't return anything, shuffling is made on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12345) # For repeatable results
np.random.shuffle(data)
```

Shuffling is done in place.

Comment: Check that your `data` is loaded properly. It works for me when I copy and pasted the array you gave.